# Unable to boot after cloning SSD drive with NVME drive. Nothing to do in bios - no disk is viable in uefi

Tags: boot, partitioning, ssd

I was cloning my SSD Samsung drive with NVMe 980 pro with magician. I can't boot at all now. I tried to do everything in bios, then first unplugged one disk then another, nothing worked so far. Uefi doesn't even recognize any disks and when I tried to use uefi + legacy it looks like I did erase my 980 pro and did clone my data to my Sata, since it doesn't have any space left just 1000kb.

I'm currently trying to figure out if I can do anything in command prompt. It looks like there are 5 volumes on Sata disk and nothing on 980 pro.
Volume 0 is labelled as recovery 300 mb healthy.
Volume 1-3 nothing special.
Volume 4 is FAT32 100 mb healthy hidden.

I have noticed there is asterisk mark under GPT at my Sata disk (list disk), but it wasn't marked as GPT so presumably 980 pro was MBR? I changed it so it has GPT and asterisk too, but for now I'm clueless what to do next. Please help me out.

[image]

Comment: It is very hard to understand what disks are you talking about. We don't know your system setup. Refer to disks expicitly, not by their connector. How the hell should we know what you mean by "your Sata", for example.

Comment: Some screenshots might help us understand.

Comment: My Sata is disk is Samsung 840 Evo 250 GBs, my NVMe is Samsung 980 pro. I wish I could provide screenshot, but I'm on mobile. That's all I can do https://imgur.com/gallery/PQ66lH3

Comment: @John is there anything I can do though?  It happened, I do have a serious issue if I won't recover it somehow, all of my important data will get lost. It doesn't help me, that you wouldn't do that... I shouldn't do that also.

Comment: @hatalmasalma please limit yourself to professional language on this site. While it may be too late to edit your existing comment, can you please try, and if you cannot, delete it and re-post it without the unnecessary language.

Comment: Please EDIT your post and add specific information, including the drives you're working with, the specific steps you took in the software, any messages you were shown along the way, etc.  Comments are not where more information should be added. Your goal right now is to make your question as complete and clear as possible.